# mysql - UPDATE with LIMIT x, y

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE table SET checked = 1 WHERE field = 'xxx' LIMIT 1
```

works fine, but

```
UPDATE table SET checked = 1 WHERE field = 'xxx' LIMIT 1, 10
```

throw error "*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 10' at line 1*"

Why it is not possible? I want to update everything except first row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LIMIT` in an `UPDATE` clause is merely an upper limit on how many rows may be updated.

It's not like in a `SELECT` where you can ignore all but a certain subrange of result rows to deal with.

If you really need something like this, you should use a `VIEW` with the `LIMIT` restriction, and perform the `UPDATE` on that.

Comment: Well, it actually makes sence but isn't supported in mysql ;-)

Comment: I'm confused. So this DOES work or it DOESN'T work? I have the same issue as OP.

Comment: @AndrewFox: What? The original query is invalid, which is why the OP and yourself had an issue. The solution is given in my final sentence.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I'm trying to do the same thing as the OP, use `LIMIT 5, 10` but it obviously doesn't work. My previous comment was actually a bit of a reaction to @zerkms first comment that it isn't supported in mysql. That confused me, because the answer was accepted and the OP used the tag mysql. Hopefully I made some sense here :\

Comment: @AndrewFox: He wasn't referring to the solution; he was referring to `LIMIT 5, 10`.

Comment: OHHHH, ok, that makes sense! I've done a search on this `VIEW` you speak of, but I don't really get it. Any chance you feel like adding an example to your answer?

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the reply, and for the link. I read through that once before (after reading this question) and I don't understand it. This might be because I'm use to running a query through php and not directly through the sql engine, I don't know. I'm truly not just being lazy and looking for an easy answer, it's not my style.

Comment: This answer _could_ use an example. Unfortunately I don't have time to add one at the present moment.

Answer (score 9):

```
update table set checked = 1 where id in (select * from (select id from table where field = 'xxx' order by id limit 1, 10) as t)
```

Comment: That works actually. Normally mysql does not support limits in subqueries, but the trick with embedding the query in yet another query does it!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, but in my case I needed to update only 2 rows ordered by a numerical ID, so my query would've been like this:

`UPDATE myTable
SET Column1='some data',Column2='some othe data'
WHERE Column3='some criteria' LIMIT 1;`

`UPDATE myTable
SET Column1='some data',Col2='some othe data'
WHERE Column3='some criteria2' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;`

Note: The first query implicitly selects the first matching row in the table, and the second query selects the second matching row by explicitly reversing the order.  It doesn't answer the question but it may benefit someone with problem similar to mine.