# PHP - While loop causing memory limit reach constantly

Tags: php, while-loop, cron

I have the following while loop, which run **one** time each day:

```
$QUERY_AVG_RENTED_SQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `xeon_users_rented` WHERE `clicks` > 0;") or _OP_CRON_00_00_ERROR(mysql_error(), __FILE__, __LINE__);    
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($QUERY_AVG_RENTED_SQL)){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `xeon_users_rented` SET `avg` = '"._OP_AVG($r['since'], $r['clicks'])."' WHERE `xeon_users_rented`.`id` = {$r['id']} LIMIT 1;") or _OP_CRON_00_00_ERROR(mysql_error(), __FILE__, __LINE__);
}
```

This is the function it runs for each user:

```
function _OP_AVG($time, $clicks){
    $avg['time_1'] = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', time()), date('d', time()), date('Y', time()));
    $avg['time_2'] = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $time), date('d', $time), date('Y', $time));
    $avg['time_3'] = $avg['time_1'] - $avg['time_2'];
    $avg['days'] = floor( $avg['time_3'] / 86400 );

    if($avg['days'] == 0 || $clicks == 0){
        return number_format( 0 , 3 );
    } else {
        return number_format( ($clicks / $avg['days']), 3 );
    }
}
```

In my `xeon_users_rented` table I have around 140k records.

I have set the `memory_limit` in `php.ini` to `400M` however I need to increase this limit every day, or else my cron job wont run the file, due to it reaches it memory limit.

Is there another way I can loop above, without creating this bottleneck?

Comment: Check [UPDATE with LIMIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773694/mysql-update-with-limit-x-y)

Comment: @Saty: But what does that have to do with PHP running out of memory?

Comment: Your function naming convention is weird and mysql_* functions have been deprecated for a *very* long time in favor of things such as PDO.

Comment: Are you really sure you need to run a separate `UPDATE` query for each result of the `SELECT` query? Normally that is done in one. If that really cannot be done, then you should think about a queuing system instead of trying to execute everything in a single script.

Comment: @Saty But i need to Update all records?

Comment: @arkascha i need to Update all records, each having a unique AVG value

Comment: @arkascha I don't know. I can't see how though, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Still you should be able to do that in a single query. If you implement that function inside the sql server, so as "stored procedure", then you can use it inside an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: I think `UPDATE xeon_users_rented AS r SET r.avg = FORMAT(r.clicks / FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - r.since) / 86400), 3)` would do it for you in one go... providing I have worked out your issue correctly (and I haven't balls'd up the SQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [mysql_unbuffered_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php)

```
$UPDATE = array();
$QUERY_AVG_RENTED_SQL = mysql_unbuffered_query("SELECT * FROM `xeon_users_rented` WHERE `clicks` > 0;") or _OP_CRON_00_00_ERROR(mysql_error(), __FILE__, __LINE__);    
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($QUERY_AVG_RENTED_SQL)){
    // We can't send another mysql_query while unbufered query did not finished
    $UPDATE[] = "UPDATE `xeon_users_rented` SET `avg` = '"._OP_AVG($r['since'], $r['clicks'])."' WHERE `xeon_users_rented`.`id` = {$r['id']} LIMIT 1;";
}

foreach ($UPDATE as $query) {
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

And You really should consider switching to [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and using prepared statements.